# .htaccess - How to set a custom header according to an environement variable?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, if-statement

How to set a custom header via .htaccess according to an environement variable using If/Else directive?

```
#Refresh-page
<If "%{ENV:DOCUMENT} == 'loading'">
    Header set Refresh "3"
</If>
```

I am trying to use the syntax described in the documentation for Apache 2.4

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

**TEST 1**

According to anubhava's answer

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:DOCUMENT} ^widget$
RewriteRule ^.* - [E=REFRESH:1]

#refresh page
Header set Refresh "3" env=REFRESH

RewriteCond %{ENV:REFRESH} ^1$
RewriteRule ^.* loading.html [L]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alter your env variable to store 0 or 1 and then you can use `Header set` like this:

You can use:

```
# set DOCUMENT=widget (remove if you are already setting this)
SetEnvIf Host ^ DOCUMENT=widget

# set isDoc=1 if DOCUMENT == widget
SetEnvIf DOCUMENT widget isDoc

# set header only if isDoc == 1
Header set Refresh "3" env=isDoc
```

Comment: [Check this documentation for setenvif examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)

Comment: Thanks anubhava I am editing the question according to your suggestion

Comment: Can you please review the code test1 and tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Actually instead of `RewriteRule` you must use `SetEnvIf` to create the new env variable (since mod_rewrite runs later in the chain). I will update the answer in few minutes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64308/discussion-between-rafasashi-and-anubhava).